# graphical password using php

Tags: php

We are doing a project on image based graphical password. We are using php. During registration the user is provided with a set of images  where he can choose an image. Then the image will be sliced and shown as a 3x3 grid. From this the user can choose a particular picture cell. A text provided by the user will be steganoed into this sliced piece. That steganoed image is stored in the database. Next time the user logs in , he has to choose the right image, the right cell and the right word. A new steganoed image is produced which is compared with the original one from database. If same, logged in..... is this feasible in php? I have been able to slice the image into a 3x3 grid. I have a steg program in php.

Comment: Aah..You remember me of my school days..got a school project here

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible in php or practically any language for than matter, the only limit is you. Start simple and build on it, that's my advice.